# scrapy - call process_exception on http code

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I want to change proxy service depends on http response code (ex. on code=500 or 404) I would like to trigger `process_exception` to change proxy address. I have created my own `proxyMiddleware` where I set proxy in `process_request`, and for ex. when timeout proxy occure the `process_exception` is called by default. But how can I trigger it on custom http status?

From scrapy docs:

> Scrapy calls process_exception() when a download handler or a
>   process_request() (from a downloader middleware) raises an exception
>   (including an IgnoreRequest exception)

but I dont know how to achieve this.

**EDIT**
my spider code

```
class Spider1(CrawlSpider):
#     pageNumber = 0

    keyword = ''
    page = range(0, 40, 10)

    allowed_domains = ['http://somedomain.com/search.html?query=football']
    start_urls = ['http://somedomain.com/search.html?query=football']
    rules = (Rule (LxmlLinkExtractor(), callback="parse", follow=True),) 

    def parse(self, response):
        return item
```

my settings.py:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    't.useragentmiddleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.retry.RetryMiddleware': 500,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.redirect.RedirectMiddleware': 600,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.cookies.CookiesMiddleware':720,
    't.cookiesmiddleware.CookiesMiddleware': 700,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 760,
    't.proxymiddleware.ProxyMiddleware': 750
}
REDIRECT_ENABLED = True
```

and proxymiddleware.py:

```
import json, os, random, socket
import t as spider1
import scrapy.exceptions as exception

socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)

class ProxyMiddleware(object):

    proxy = ''
    proxyList = []
    handle_httpstatus_list = [302, 400]

    def __init__(self, settings):
        f = open(t.location + '/data/proxy.json')
        self.proxyList = json.load(f)['proxy']
        f.close()

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if 'proxy' in request.meta:
            return

        self.proxy = 'http://' + random.choice(self.proxyList)

        os.environ['http_proxy'] = self.proxy
        request.meta['proxy'] = self.proxy


    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings)

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        proxy = request.meta['proxy']

        try:
            del self.proxyList[self.proxyList.index(proxy[8:])]
        except ValueError:
            pass
        prox = 'http://' + random.choice(self.proxyList)
        request.meta['proxy'] = prox
        os.environ['http_proxy'] = prox

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        '''this doesn't work'''
        #raise exception.NotConfigured()
```

Answer (score 1):

Valid HTTP status codes are not 'exceptions', so they are routed through `process_response`. Extract a method and call it from both `process_exception` and `process_response`.

```
CHANGE_PROXY_STATUS_LIST = [502, 404]

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def change_proxy(request):
        # Change proxy here
        # Then check number of retries on the request 
        # and decide if you want to give it another chance.
        # If not - return None else
        return request  

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        return_request = change_proxy(request)
        if return_request: 
            return return_request

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if response.status in CHANGE_PROXY_STATUS_LIST:
            return_request = change_proxy(request)
            if return_request: 
                return return_request
        return response
```